# navigation Bar is not showing up completely in my modal View

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, navigationbar

i am using the following code to present a modal View but still my navigation bar is hiding behind the status bar.

I can only see half of my Navigation bar ..
Plz point out my error and Suggest me the solution to it.

```
 tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init ];
 UINavigationController *cntrol = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tabBarController];
NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNav,secondNav,thirdNav,fourthNav,fifthNav, nil];  
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;  
tabBarController.selectedIndex=type;
[self presentModalViewController:cntrol animated:NO];
```

here firstNav, secondNav,thirdNav, fourthNav and fifthNav are the instatnces of UINavigationController.

Comment: @mbh self is again a viewController here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabBarControllers are not meant to live inside navigation controllers, but each tab of a TabBarController can be a NavigationController.    I've never tried to display a TabBarController modally but I suppose it should work.   Switch the nesting of the TabBarController/NavigationController and it should work.